# Navigation Menu is overriding normal list items

Tags: html, css

For some reason my navigation menu is overriding my normal list items.

My HTMl code is on pastebin:

[HTML Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WVe8rTEP)

Here is some of my CCS code:

```
body {
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

My CSS is continued on pastebin here:

[CSS Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xZ9ubJHs)

[image: List items not right]

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a fiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because you are adding CSS to HTML elements and not using CSS Classes and or ID selectors to differentiate what you want to style. To differentiate the navigation list styles from the list style you will use through out your site use the following.

HTML

```
<ul class='nav'>
 <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Newswire</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Social Club</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Warehouse</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 text-align: center;
  li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

}

Comment: I don't want to change the navigation menu. I want to change the list items in the screenshot above.

Comment: You still need to use CSS classes to make your CSS more specific. Make a CSS class called **.list** and add all the styles you want to style the list items, then make sure you add the **.list** css class to the **ul** element of the tag. Below is a link to CSS best practices that should help https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/challenging-css-best-practices-atomic-approach/